# Alias for datatypes in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

So I've got a structure like this:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

but I want a structure that is defined as

```
data MaybeInt = Nothing | Just Int
```

is there a way to define `MaybeInt` using `Maybe a`, and if so how?

Comment: Is `type MaybeInt = Maybe Int` what you meant?

Comment: `type`, yeah, but don't do this, use synonyms when they actually mean something — `MaybeInt` buys you absolutely nothing over `Maybe Int`.

Comment: Perhaps, I'll test it soon. MaybeInt is to satisfy a type interface. Put that as a solution and I'll approve it if it's correct.

Comment: @DanielFath What kind of type interface? Haskell should accept `Maybe Int` everywhere where `MaybeInt` would be accepted.

Comment: It's a function interface like this `convert::Maybe -> Int`. Does this clear up the confusion? I'd like for Maybe to not be generic, simply as a challenge/experiment.

Comment: @DanielFath: Then you'd simply have `convert :: Maybe Int -> Int`.

Comment: @DanielFath Note that `Maybe -> Int` is not a valid type signature. And whether you write `MaybeInt -> Int` or `Maybe Int -> Int` with the type synonym makes absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few ways to define `MaybeInt`. I'll state them then have some commentary.

*Direct*

```
data MaybeInt = NothingInt | JustInt Int
```

*Newtype*

```
newtype MaybeInt = MI (Maybe Int)
```

*Type synonym*

```
type MaybeInt = Maybe Int
```

*Plain*

```
-- just use `(Maybe Int)` wherever you would write `MaybeInt`
```

**Commentary**

Most commonly, one would use the *plain* method since most people are familiar with `Maybe` and thus know to use `Just` and `Nothing` to match it. This makes it good for libraries—very transparent. The *type synonym* method is a common documentation method, but is basically useless for your synonym. It makes it so that `foo :: Int -> Maybe Int` and `bar :: Int -> MaybeInt` have identical type signatures. It also means that as soon as someone knows that `MaybeInt === Maybe Int` they can use the `Just`/`Nothing` constructors for matching.

The *newtype* method gets fairly interesting. Here you have to begin "wrapping" and "unwrapping" the `MI` *constructor* every time you want to use the `MaybeInt` *type*. Compare:

```
baz :: MaybeInt -> Bool
baz (MI Nothing) = False
baz (MI (Just int)) = True
```

this is nice because if you don't *export* `MI` then nobody will be able to match on `MaybeInt` (despite having a pretty good guess at what's going on inside of it). This is really useful for making stable APIs. Another interesting property of `newtype` is that you can write new `instance`s for `MaybeInt` which are different from `Maybe`'s built-in ones. For instance, you could override the `Monoid` instance

```
instance Monoid MaybeInt where
  mempty = MI Nothing
  mi `mappend` (MI Nothing) = mi
  _  `mappend` mi           = mi
```

which is just the same as the `Last a` newtype built-in to `Data.Monoid` which wraps `Maybe a`s.

Finally, we get the full-blown `data` instance. It's more verbose, more likely to error, marginally slower (since the compiler has to track a new, unique data type), and requires that people learn new constructors. For functionality so obviously identical to `Maybe Int` there's really no reason to use it at all.

Comment: +1, but the `Monoid` instance looks suspicious. `MI (Just x) <> mempty` should be `MI (Just x)`. This works, though: `x \`mappend\` (MI Nothing) = x; _ \`mappend\` y = y`

Comment: Oh, yeah, total error there! It's a valid `Monoid` instance... just a sort of terrible one. Fixed now.